# Angular how to save value of option when options are generated using ngFor

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a list of objects named Fixtures.
Inside every fixture there is a list of objects named FixtureParticipants.
This is what I do to create options:

```
<tr *ngFor="let fixture of fixtures$ | async; let i=index">
  <th scope="row"> {{i + 1 }} </th>
  <th scope="row">{{ fixture.id }}</th>
  <th scope="row">
    <select class="form-select form-select-sm" [ngModel]="selectedFixtureParticipant$" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)">
      <option selected disabled>Select Fixture Participant</option>
      <option *ngFor="let fixtureParticipant of fixture.fixtureParticipants" [value]="fixtureParticipant">{{ fixtureParticipant.participantId }}</option>
    </select>
  </th>
  <th scope="row">{{ fixture.sportId }}</th>
  <th scope="row">{{ fixture.locationId }}</th>
  <th scope="row">{{ fixture.leagueId }}</th>
  <th scope="row">{{ fixture.startDate.replace("T", " ") }}</th>
</tr>
```

and here is the typescript component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'fixtures',
  templateUrl: './fixtures.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./fixtures.component.css']
})
export class FixturesComponent implements OnInit{
  fixtures$: Observable<any> | undefined;
  selectedFixtureParticipant$: Observable<any> | undefined;

  constructor(private _service: WebSocketService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.fixtures$ = this._service.getFixtures();
  }

  onChange(newValue: any) {
    console.log(newValue);
    this.selectedFixtureParticipant$ = newValue;
  }

}
```

What it does now is when I choose an option in 1 select, it changes the option in all select boxes.
also, when I try to console.log the object, it returns [Object object]. When I try to do console.log(JSON.stringify(newValue)) it logs "[Object object]".
How can I fix it? I just want to save the current selected object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<th scope="row">
    <select class="form-select form-select-sm" [(ngModel)]="selectedFixtureParticipant$">
      <option selected disabled>Select Fixture Participant</option>
      <option *ngFor="let fixtureParticipant of fixture.fixtureParticipants" [ngValue]="fixtureParticipant">{{ fixtureParticipant.id }}</option>
    </select>
    {{ selectedFixtureParticipant$ | json}}
  </th>
```

turns out there was a very easy solution..... idk wth i was stuck on lol

```
    @Component({
  selector: 'fixtures',
  templateUrl: './fixtures.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./fixtures.component.css']
})
export class FixturesComponent{
  fixtures$: Observable<any>;
  selectedFixtureParticipant$: Observable<any> | undefined;

  constructor(private _service: WebSocketService) {
    this.fixtures$ = this._service.getFixtures();
  }
}
```